# IIS Server не подключается к MS SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, iis, asp

Всем привет. Есть приложение, которое запустив с Visual Studio подключается к SQL Server. Но стоит запустить его с SQL Server, выходит ошибка **Request failed with status code 500**.
Вот строка подключения `Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DB;Trusted_Connection=True;Integrated_Security=false;`

В чем может быть дело? Почему со студии подключение к БД проходит успешно, а с IIS Server нет? Ведь строка подключения одна и та же. Может нужно какие-то разрешения задать?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Проверьте учетку, от которой запущен пул приложений IIS, скорее всего у нее нет доступа к sql серверу

Comment: Ну и найдите конкретное сообщение ошибки, что в нем написано.

Comment: "Но стоит запустить его с SQL Server" - может быть IIS, а не SQL?

Comment: Как я могу найти сообщение об ошибке. Т.е лог файл от IIS?

Comment: Есть еще проблема. При добавлении IIS_IUSRS в SQL Server Management Studio выходит ошибка что IIS_IUSRS не найдены.

Comment: И почему то LocalService, LocalSystem тоже не подключаются